# The unitization of an algebra is the optimal way to endow an algebra with an identity

Tags: abstract-algebra

> **Definition:** Given a non-unital $\mathbb{F}$-algebra A, the *unitization* of A is the $\mathbb{F}$-algebra $\mathbb{F}\times A$ with operations defined as follows:
>
> $$\text{(Vector addition)}: (\alpha, a) + (\alpha',a') = (\alpha+\alpha',a+a'),
>  $$ $$\text{(Scalar product)}: \mu(\alpha,a) = (\mu\alpha,\mu a)$$
> $$\text{(Bilinear product)}: (\alpha,a)(\alpha',a') = (\alpha \alpha',\alpha a'+\alpha'a +aa' )$$
> for all $\alpha,\alpha',\mu \in \mathbb{F}, a,a' \in A$.

My professor said me that the unitization of a non-unital $\mathbb{F}$-algebra $A$ is the optimal way to endow A with an identity but she didn't precise that. Formally, what means that $\mathbb{F} \times A$ is optimal? How can I prove that?

Comment: One thing to take care with is that $\mathbb F\times A$ is just the underlying set of this unitization. There is another $\mathbb F$-algebra called $\mathbb F\times A$ which is different. Inside this question, it is safe to call it $\mathbb F\times A,$ but elsewhere you should give it a name like $u(A)$ for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, “optimal” is a bad choice of words. There is a sense in which is is the most “natural” way to include $A$ in a unital algebra.

This is a case of something called a “universal property.”

Specifically: Given any $\phi:A\to B$ where $B$ is a unital $\mathbb F-$algebra, there is a unique map $\mathbb F\times A\to B$ so that $A\to\mathbb F\times A\to B$ is $\phi.$

In some sense, $\mathbb F\times A$ is the “first” way to add a unit to $A.$

We often have “universal properties” like this. For example, you can define a free group on a set using a universal property.

Comment: Is it equivalent to say that the category of $\mathbb{F}$-algebras with unity is a **reflective subcategory** of the category of $\mathbb{F}$-algebras through the unitization?

Comment: Not sure, because I'm not sure if unital algebras are a full subcategory of the algebras. If $A,B$ are unital algebras, perhaps there are maps $A\to B$ that are homomorphisms which aren't unital homomorphisms? But yes, unitization is an adjoint to the forgetful functor from unital $\mathbb F$-algebras to all $\mathbb F$-algebras. @JohnMars

Comment: For example, if $A$ is unital, then so is $A\times A,$ and there is a map $A\to.A\times A$, $a\mapsto (a,0)$, which is a homomorphism of algebras, but not a homomorphism of unital algebras. names

Comment: The inclusion is the forgetful functor. The inclusion is unital algebras being a subcategory of all algebras, which is also the forgetful functor. But, as I've shown, unital algebras are not a full subcategory of all algebras. (Wikipedia says **full** subcategory is required for a reflective subcategory.) (Indeed, I'm not sure if there is a technical definition of forgetful functors, but if so, the nature is almost certainly that of inclusion.) @JohnMars

Comment: Associativity is not a necessary condition to be an algebra, maybe it could spoil a desired unity-preserving property of homomorphism; could we generalized your example to characterize this fact?

Comment: You'll have to be more specific, I can't tell what you are saying about "desired unity-preserving property." @JohnMars

Comment: I'm referring to homomorphism preserving unities...

Comment: I've already shown that algebras don't necessarily preserve unity with the $A\to A\times A$ example. @JohnMars We don't need to have more than one such example to prove that the subcategory isn't full.

Comment: Just curious... On the other side, I can't say that it is reflective, but using that the forgetful functor admits left adjoint, what can we conclude in Algebra terms?

Comment: I honestly don't know here. I'm at the limit of my remembered category theory. @JohnMars

Comment: Also, reflectors are supposed to be idempotent. So $u(u(A))\cong u(A)$ would be true if unitization functor $u$ is reflective. But we can see this is not the case for $u(A)$ easily, at least for  finite $\mathbb F$ and $\mathbb A,$ by counting elements.